# Estimate range of every row in R

Tags: r, range

We did a survey where 60 students had to vote their favorite ideas. you could select three ideas. The best idea gets 3 points, the next 2 and the third best idea 1 point. columns 2 to 10 correspond to the ideas.

So to check if everyone did the survey correctly I used the command

```
rowSums(x[,2:10], na.rm=T)
```

This works.

But next to that I would like to check the range for every row with the following command:

```
rowRanges(x, rows = NULL, cols=NULL, na.rm=T, dim.=dim(x[,2:10])
```

But here is a mistake. Can you help me?

Comment: Is rowRanges a function from library(matrixStats) ? Would be good if you could provide a small (fictive) dataset.

Comment: Could you tell us what mistake /error message you got?

Comment: Sorry for the missing information.  I used the apply() command.

but for further details:
10 colums: (1- person; 2-idea 1, 3-idea 2; 4-idea 3, ..., 10-idea 9)
60 rows (each row represents the vote of a student)

e.g. student 1 votes 3 points for idea 2, two points for idea 6, and one point for idea 8

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example using `apply` on `mtcars` data.

```
df = mtcars
df$cars = rownames(df)
df = df[,c(12,1:10)]
rownames(df) = NULL

df$sums = apply(df[,2:10], 1, function(x) sum(x, na.rm = TRUE))
df$range = apply(df[,2:10], 1, function(x)
                paste(max(x,na.rm = TRUE)," - ",min(x, na.rm = TRUE),sep = ""))
```

Answer (score 1):

Load the library matrixStats

```
library(matrixStats)
```

First create a fictive matrix, 15 rows and 15 columns, containing random numbers between 1-3.

```
m1<-matrix(sample(3, 225, replace=TRUE), nrow=15)
```

Then use the function rowRanges

```
rowRanges(m1[,2:10])
```

Comment: maybe you misunderstood me. I have already the real data of the students. so there is no need to create a sample.
60 students completed the survey and we have the data in an excel sheet. so do I have to convert the excel data into a matrix?

Comment: He's created a sample to demonstrate that it works on the sample, since you haven't provided your data or a subset of it.

Comment: @ Chris: no worries, I just asked for a dataset to inspect the error and test my solution, that is why I made quickly a fictive dataset myself. Please let me know if the 'rowRanges' solution works now.